# How to create function that classifies sample data

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, data

I want to create expression, that classifies samples ( 4 weather features -> decision).

Example training data:

[image]

For the values that i have data for, I can use rules:

```
fs = {
   {0, 0, 0, 0} -> 1, {2, 1, 0, 0} -> 1, {2, 2, 1, 0} -> 1, {0, 2, 1, 1} -> 1,
   {1, 2, 1, 0} -> 1, {2, 1, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 1, 1, 1} -> 1, {0, 1, 0, 1} -> 1,
   {0, 0, 1, 0} -> 1, {1, 0, 0, 0} -> 0, {1, 0, 0, 1} -> 0, {2, 2, 1, 1} -> 0,
   {1, 1, 0, 0} -> 0, {2, 1, 0, 1} -> 0};
{2, 1, 0, 1} /. fs
```

Alternatively I can use table/hashmap:

```
fs[{0, 0, 0, 0}] = 1;
fs[{2, 1, 0, 0}] = 1;
(*etc.*)
fs[{2, 1, 0, 1}]
```

How can I compute an estimation decision based on closest* existing sample element(s)?

> closeness can be defined by any distance function ex: {euclidean distance,hamming distance,...}.

Comment: I don't know that I understand your application but can you not use a list of replacement rules directly?

Comment: Tally of the feature vectors shows the sample values are unique, so there exist one (or more) functions into the decision space. However, n=14 whereas there are 3*3*2*2=36 presumably possible values of feature vectors - so it's necessary to specify a loss function b/c it is the generalization on unseen data that matters. Otherwise, as Mr.Wizard states, just use example rules directly.

Comment: You mention a decision tree, were you thinking of C4.5 or CART type decision trees ?

Comment: See the answer of a similar question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75801/creating-identification-classification-trees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, just do, using your `fs`

```
classify=Nearest[fs];
```

or eventually

```
classify=Nearest[fs, DistanceFunction->distFun]
```

where `distFun` can be `EuclideanDistance`, `HammingDistance`, .... Then you just do

```
classify[data]
```

to get your result